Angular client side dynamic route redirect to wildcard route on page reload
In angular app I have hundreds of dynamic routes. Which are added in route config after an API call.
But when I reload the same page with dynamic route, browser send the request to server and return as 404 not found.
Client side route are not resolved at server side.
for adding dynamic route I am using
fetch('./assets/static-json/all-schools.json').then()
which is an async call in App_Initializer_service.
I want whenever app load in browser everytime app detects the json file changes.
import * as data from '/assets/static-json/all-schools.json';
compiled once and then not detecting changes

Can you post a bit more context and code? Maybe of the section where you load the routes? With the current description it is quite hard to identify any problem further than an educated guess.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Angular handles routing on client-side, and when you reload a page with dynamic routes, the server has no idea about these routes and would return 404 if route not found on server.
Solution 1: change .htaccess to handle only index.html in rewrite rule in this way server side wont give 404 and will fall back to index.html which is your angular's App index.html. In this file the angular's routing would take over.
Solution 2: Detect changes in json file in an AppIntializerService.
  @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root',
    })
 export class AppInitializerService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) {}

  initializeApp(): Promise<any> {
    return this.http.get('/assets/static-json/all-schools.json')
      .toPromise()
      .then((data: any) => {
        // Assuming your data is an array of dynamic routes
        data.forEach((route: any) => {
          this.router.config.push({
            path: route.path,
            component: route.component,
            // Add any route properties here
          });
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Failed to load dynamic routes:', error);
      });
  }
}

and provide it in root
// App initializer provider
export function appInitializerFactory(appInitializerService: AppInitializerService) {
  return () => appInitializerService.initializeApp();
}

your module provider will then look like
// In your module providers array:
providers: [
  {
    provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
    useFactory: appInitializerFactory,
    deps: [AppInitializerService],
    multi: true,
  },
],

